# Validation on an external model object using play framework 1.2.5

Tags: validation, playframework-1.x

I have a model object which is defined outside of my play application, it is an auto-generated entity produced from wsdl. This means that I can't reliably add validation annotations to its fields. I thought about extending the class and in fact that's what I've done, and I wonder if its possible to add validation tags to the extended version? An immediate problem that I see with that however is that it also has children who's members would also need validation tags added, and if i were to extend them, they would not be used by play's binder. I guess what I need is some kind of custom validator, but from what I can see they are aimed at validation single properties, not entire object models.

Any pointers or suggestions would be great
Cheers!
NFV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write custom validator for your class and use:

```
public static void myController(@CheckWith(MyValidator.class) myParameter)
```

in controller to test if objects are valid. Then just manually validate them inside `MyValidator` (it has to extend `play.data.validation.Check`).
Check [play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/validation#custom) for more info about custom validators.